# How to make a Blacklist application?

Tags: android, blacklist

I am trying to build an Blacklisting application where I would be able Blacklist certain numbers. i am completely new to Android so would you please give me some ideas.

Comment: For outgoing, incoming, or both?  Outgoing is fairly easy, incoming isn't as simple-  Google has been removing ways of answering and ending calls as quickly as they pop up, for security reasons (malware that cancels all your calls would be annoying and quite possibly a legal issue with 911 calls)

Comment: I am trying to implement it for incoming calls
I found other apps at playstore so thought it was possible to do for my project but so far got no success

Comment: It might be possible (although I'm not sure those apps work on all versions of Android, they may work only on older ones).  It's going to be messy and require you to skirt around a few limitations Google wants to put on you.

Comment: yeah the from the playstore did work on my phone which contatin 4.1.1 jellybean
and i found that there is an in-built feature in kitkat to block the incoming calls and messages
so i tried to do the same 
but upon my research i found nothing helpful